# Ruby on rails. How safe is an admin attribute for user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, devise, admin

I can't find any definitive answers to this. 
I have a user model with devise, and I have added an 'admin' attribute that is a boolean, which defaults to false. Currently I have to go to the console and manually change the attribute to true to give a user this admin status.

My question is, how secure is this? Is there any way for someone to change the status of their own user without accessing the server (Currently my computer)?
Could safety be compromised once I put the site into production? The admin attribute is not a permitted parameter on sign in, sign up or update.

I am asking as I want to add a personal dashboard for myself to view, edit or delete anything I might need to when the site goes into production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Devise, safety is the last thing that could go wrong, unless either one of Rails or Devise is broken, which is unlikely. 
You have taken sufficient steps like not allowing the `admin` parameter, which should be enough for pretty much every situation. 
Several Rails applications, including GitHub and Shopify have been doing this (possibly without Devise, but that's not a concern) without security issues. I myself use Devise and admin flags and can vouch that it is safe enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [strong params](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) then the risk is only if you allow setting this attribute from any action outside of admin panel.

To be extra safe you can use `attr_readonly` so you can only set this attribute when object is created.

Comment: Thankyou for clearing up my concerns and for your suggestion. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you are not using something like [RoleModel](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model)? It will allow you to expand to other roles in the future in a much more manageable way than adding an attribute to User for each role.

Either way... unless you provide a way for them to update that field, it should be secure. If you want to ensure that there's no way a non-admin could update that field, you could always add something like this to UsersController#update:

```
params[:user].delete(:admin) unless current_user.admin?
```

Comment: I have 2 user roles using a boolean for the site, and an admin boolean for 1 page for myself. I can see no foreseeable reason why I would need to add more roles. Thanks for clearing up my concerns and I will bear your suggestion in mind.